# c# Error - "Specified cast is not valid"

Tags: c#, linq, casting, dataset

I'm getting a "specified cast is not valid" error inside the where clause of my linq to datatable query. I just can't seem to figure out what is wrong with it. I would imagine its the the paramValues causing the issue because they are of type object, but I am doing a Convert.ToInt32 on each one.  I am still receiving the error. Just to note, all the columns in the datatable are type int. Any ideas?

```
protected DataRow getSubjectBandDataRow(DataSet relationalDataSet, DataRow dr, Parameters Params)
{
        DataRow myRow = relationalDataSet.Tables["SummaryDataLocalBands"].NewRow();
        myRow["fkSummarySubjectLocalID"] = (from subj in relationalDataSet.Tables["SummaryDataLocal"].AsEnumerable()
                                           where (subj.Field<int>("fkRosterSetID") == Convert.ToInt32(Params.Item(2).ParamValue) && 
                                                  subj.Field<int>("fkTestInstanceID") == dr.Field<int>("pkTestInstanceID") &&
                                                  subj.Field<int>("fkTestTypeID") == Convert.ToInt32(Params.Item(10).ParamValue) && 
                                                  subj.Field<int>("fkSchoolYearID") == dr.Field<int>("pkSchoolYearID") && 
                                                  subj.Field<int>("fkRosterTypeID") == 1 && 
                                                  subj.Field<int>("fkDistrictID") == (Convert.ToInt32(Params.Item(3).ParamValue) == 0 ? 1 : 0) &&
                                                  subj.Field<int>("fkSchoolID") == Convert.ToInt32(Params.Item(3).ParamValue) && 
                                                  subj.Field<int>("fkGradeID") == Convert.ToInt32(Params.Item(5).ParamValue) &&
                                                  subj.Field<int>("fkDepartmentID") == Convert.ToInt32(Params.Item(6).ParamValue) && 
                                                  subj.Field<int>("fkCourseID") == Convert.ToInt32(Params.Item(7).ParamValue) &&
                                                  subj.Field<int>("fkPeriodID") == Convert.ToInt32(Params.Item(8).ParamValue) && 
                                                  subj.Field<int>("fkDemoCommonCategoryID") == dr.Field<int>("fkDemoCommonCategotyID") &&
                                                  subj.Field<int>("fkDemoCommonCodeID") == Convert.ToInt32(Params.Item(1).ParamValue) && 
                                                  subj.Field<int>("fkTest_SubjectID") == dr.Field<int>("fkTest_SubjectID"))
                                           select subj.Field<int>("pkSummarySubjectLocalID")).Single();  

        //more unimportant code here

        return myRow;
    }
```

Comment: It's extremely hard to tell with just this amount of information. However, I noticed this: `fkDemoCommonCategotyID` which has a typo in Categoty. Perhaps this line is returning null which is failing to cast to int? To further debug, I'd move all the Convert.Int32() calls to the top (ie, convert and store to a variable). This will let you narrow down exactly which line is failing

Comment: Check all your `params` to see if there's a null or string which can't be converted to int.

Comment: good catch Rob.  I was about to ask for the line that calls this function.  Everything otherwise looks good here, so it would certainly be a Param issue as expected, but on the calling side, and not here.

Comment: @Rob super great catch thank you. That is definitely something that would contribute to the issue. My guess is that it has to do with one of the ParamValues which are a string but can be converted to an int like "100" for example. Any way to convert that properly (A type of object that could be a string but also an int)

Comment: @RyanGray To convert from a string to int, you can use `int.Parse()` or `int.TryParse()`. As for whether or not it's already an int - that suggests you need sanitation of inputs earlier on. Failing that, you can use `Convert.ChangeType([value],typeof(int))`. This will do its best to convert the object into an int - but I would very much recommend fixing the sanitation issue (what happens if you're given an array, for example, as the object?)

Comment: @Rob I'm still getting the error when I try int.Parse(Convert.ToString(Params.Item(1).ParamValue)). Would this sort of thing not work even though the string can be converted to an int?

Comment: @RyanGray You'd really need to find out what is in the ParamValue. If it's an integer (not decimal), it should parse it correctly. I'd recommend doing the conversion line by line before the query, so that it fails on the exact conversion you need to fix, rather than the entire query

Answer (score 0):

The error you are seeing occurs when a specific cast can't be performed because the value of the object can't be converted to the target type. So it's likely that you have something in one of your parameters which can't be converted to an integer. For example a null, or empty string are likely candidates.

Comment: If it is a string but can be an integer, e.g. "100" can that be converted with Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToString(Params.Item(1).ParamValue)). The initial Convert.ToString is there because the ParamValue is type object